# Oracle Apex Date Picker behaving strangely

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5

I am using Oracle Apex 19.2. I am trying to build a a dynamic report based on Classic report and PL/SQL function body returning SQL statement. Simply I have two date pickers where I set a default value of `sysdate - 21` (set through dynamic action on page refresh) then I construct a simple report with the following PL/SQL

```
declare
  clsd_snc date:= :P5_CLOSED_SINCE;
  ignrd_snc date := :P5_IGNORED_SINCE;
begin
  return 'select ' || clsd_snc || ',' || ignrd_snc || ' from dual';
end;
```

I have two problems:

1. When the form loads I see the following set in the date pickers:
   `12&#x2F;15&#x2F;2019`
2. When I set the date manually to a proper date I see the following output in the report:
   `.000495049504950495049504950495049504950495`

I tried using to_date and to_char in the PL/SQL and to change the date format of the pickers but nothing is working. I would hugely appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried to do what you described, but can't reproduce it - works OK for me. Please, create a sample page on apex.oracle.com, provide login credentials so that we could look at what you did and how Apex responded.

Comment: Please login to the following account
Workspace:TRACKING_WS
Username:test@user.com
Password:APEX1234
Page 3 in the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the sample page. I copied your page 3 to page 4 (so that your "original" remains intact) and did this:

- dynamic action: turn **OFF** "Escape special characters"

  - this fixes the `12&#x2F;15&#x2F;2019` issue
- report query: enclose `clsd_snc` into single quotes (`chr(39)`)

  - this fixes the `.000495049504950` issue

    ```
    declare
      clsd_snc date := :P4_CLSD_SINCE;
    begin
      return 'select ' || chr(39) || clsd_snc || chr(39) || ' from dual';
    end;
    ```

I guess that's it; so - check page #4.

Answer (score 0):

For 1st Problem :

1. When the form loads I see the following set in the date pickers: 12/15/2019

Fix :
Change in Section Setting Format "Plain Text" by "HTML" instead